# Get current term name in Woocommerce product category archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to get single product category name of a product category archive page.

Using this code:

```
$categ = $product->get_categories(); 
echo $categ;
```

Its showing all parent category as well…

How to get the current term name in Woocommerce product category archive pages?

Answer (score 3):

To get the product category term name of the current product category archive page, you will use:

```
// Only on product category archive pages
if(is_product_category()){
    // The WP_Term object for the current product category
    $term = get_queried_object();

    // Get the current term name for the product category page
    $term_name = $term->name;

    // Test output
    echo $term->name . '<br>';
}
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what if I need to show last child category in Shop page as well. Appreciate  your reply

Comment: @DevalMungalpara Your question seems to be unclear undetailed and incomplete. We don't know where and how you use the code and it seems that you are also using ACF custom fields, which is not mentioned in your question. We don't know nothing about the versions used...