# Woocommerce : Dynamic Title with attributes on category page (with Rank Math)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, filter, attributes

I have an online store in which there are product category pages. The latter have filters to reorganize the products according to the preferences of the user. Among these filters, there are some that are interesting from an SEO point of view, for example it is possible to select only products from a particular brand.

Only, when this is done, the URL of the category page does change with "?filter_brand=name of the brand" at the end, but the Title (and the h1 incidentally) both remain identical to the original category page. This is very annoying in terms of SEO.

I know that with the Yoast SEO plugin, this change is automatic:

https://www.welaunch.io/en/knowledge-base/faq/woocommerce-seo-filter-titles/ (example with a title and a h1 that changes according to the color filter, exactly what I'm looking for)

With Rank Math (the SEO plugin I use), this is not done automatically, but it is however possible to add a snippet that can modify the Title of a page. This one :

```html
add_filter( 'rank_math/frontend/title', function( $title ) {
    return $title;
});
```

However, having a low level in PHP, I don't know what variables to modify in order to modify the title of a specific page or to make this title modification automatic as with Yoast SEO (which would suit me given number of variables and category pages).

From what I have observed, all the pages of my site have the title "Test" when I make this modification to the piece of code:

```html
add_filter( 'rank_math/frontend/title', function( $title ) {
    $title="test";
    return $title;
});
```

I think these are basic changes but I can't find any way to make the $title function apply to a specific page and not to the whole site. Even better, make him understand that the Title must include the variable "brand name" visible in the URL as with Yoast SEO so as not to have to rewrite the piece of code 100 times by modifying the variables each time.

So it's a long cobblestone for something not very rocket science but at my low level it's a real dilemma... If anyone have a solution or even a lead I'm interested. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the answer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115257/get-current-term-name-in-woocommerce-product-category-archive-pages). As mentioned there, first check if you are in product category archives, if so get the current term name for the product category page and set it to `$title` and return it. Let me know in the comment if it works.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your precious answer, it was helpful.

I ended added this snippet :

"add_filter( 'rank_math/frontend/title', function( $title ) {
    if( is_product_category() ) {
        $filter_brand = $_GET['filter_brand'];
        $filter_color = $_GET['filter_color'];
  $separator = ' - ';
        
        if ( isset($filter_brand) ) {
            $title = $filter_brand . $separator . $title;
        }

        if ( isset($filter_color) ) {
            $title = $filter_color . $separator . $title;
        }
    }
 
    return $title;
});"